# Adview in Fragment is not displaying

Tags: android, android-fragments, adsense, adview

Hi i am trying to display adview in fragment but i am not getting any result, it shows just blank area, in activity it works fine,

for fragment i wrote the code as below:

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/innerbg"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
           xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/adView"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"
           ads:adUnitId="@string/adunit_id_home"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Fragment :

```
AdView adViewHome = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adViewHome);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adViewHome.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: why it is down voted ? may i know the reason ?

Comment: i don't know why these people are down voting the question, If there is any problem then let me know so that in future i'll not repeat. without informing doing down vote is not proper way, you must correct newbies

Answer (score 1):

Your Listview is taking up the entire screen so the adview doesn't get a chance to show. Change your layout to this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView     
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adunit_id_home" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Fragment :

```
AdView adViewHome = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adViewHome);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adRequest.setTesting(true);
adViewHome.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: did you try setting the list view to wrap content?

Comment: Yes i set permissions to manifest and set listview height as wrap content

Comment: I made an edit, my last guess, set testing to true for debugging and ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" in your xml

Comment: adRequest.setTesting(true); gives error : "The method setTesting(boolean) is undefined for the type AdRequest"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82064/discussion-between-rajesh-suthar-and-modge).

Comment: ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" gives error "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 'com.example.exp'"